# Как можно получить и изменить содержимое вложенного элемента полученного через переменную?

Tags: javascript

Пример:

```js
var sell = document.getElementById("test").cells[0];

// здесь нужно получить и изменить содержимое тега b
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="test"><td><b>text</b><div></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Как можно получить и изменить содержимое вложенного элемента `b` полученного через переменную?

Comment: `sell.querySelector('b').innerHTML = '...';`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev , то что нужно , сделайте комментарий ответом отмечу как верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sell.querySelector('b').innerHTML;
```

Он и сеттер и геттер